# Close votes filter enhancement

Tags: feature-request

The [close votes](http://www.superuser.com/review/close/) allows us to filter by up to 3 tags.

Can these (and if so how) be negative values. For example, I know nothing of Linux, and as such I spend quite a while clicking the skip button. I admit, it's not a hardship, however, I'd like to be add `-linux -bash` and just have those removed totally from my results.

Comment: This would be magical. Maybe it would get more attention at http://meta.stackexchange.com/ though **edit** it has been brought up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196015/apply-filter-to-exclude-particular-tag-in-close-vote-queue

Answer (score -3):

-1 because content isn't a reason to close.  Look at the reasons to close:

> - **duplicate of...** - This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
> - **off-topic because...** - This question does not appear to be a meta discussion about Super User or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center.
> - **unclear what you're asking** - Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
> - **too broad** - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
> - **primarily opinion-based** - Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

With the *slight* exception of **off-topic becuase...** and **duplicate of...** none of these are content related but rather quality related.

Personally I don't see a need to filter out question in any way as being an expert in the questions field isn't necessary to knowing whether the question is a good fit here or not.

Comment: I don't think the OP is suggesting to close questions based on their content. IIUC, he's proposing an RFE to the filtering options. Today, you can whitelist your filters (e.g., only posts regarding [tag:windows]). Since he has little knowledge of [tag:linux] and [tag:bash], he wants to **filter out** posts with those tags.

Comment: @Mureinik I understand that the OP isn't wanting to close questions based on their content, which in turn begs the question, why filter them at all?  That's my point.

Comment: As far as I get it, the claim is as follows - "If don't know anything about subject X, so I don't feel as though I have the tools to judge the quality of a post about it. Since I skip such questions anyway, please give me a way to do this effectively".

Comment: Suppose I ask you a question about Rook OS, my fictional OS. How can you know the state/quality of the question 'how to restart the Rook OS'. You can't. You have no idea if that is broad, if it's on topic, even if it's clear (maybe the OS can't be restarted)... You would need to research the answer. Well I don't have the time to research for just a close question vote and that is why I'd have to hit skip. Or I could save the time and have it filtered, not showing it show it at all... I hope this makes more sense?

Comment: @DaveRook Even though you may not know much about the subject there's only a few times that you actually need to know about the content in order to know whether or not the question is a valid fit or not.  I can see where you're coming from, but the point of my answer is to say that content isn't and shouldn't be a reason to skip a question while reviewing.  I can understand this logic while answering, but not reviewing them as 90% of the questions that need to be closed are due to quality issues and not content.